# Error when trying to compare args with string in condition

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to do a shell script to add and delete users to a text file.
I want to use the args to compare if delete or add user, but no matter what args I put, both codes run, this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1="$1"
arg2="$2"
if [ "$arg1"="add" ]; then
 if ! grep -q $arg2 "users.txt"; then
  sed -i -e 's/users:/users: \n  - '$arg2'/g' users.txt
  echo "user added: $arg2"
 else
  echo "user exists: $arg2"
 fi
fi
if [ "$arg1"="del" ]; then
 if grep -q $arg2 "users.txt"; then
  sed -i -e 's/- '$arg2'//g' users.txt
  echo "user $arg2 deleted"
 else
  echo "not found $arg2"
 fi
fi
```

This is my text file `users.txt`:

```
users: 
  - angel
  - rick
```

Running `sh addUser.sh add user1` on terminal:

```
user added: user1
user user1 deleted
```

Running `sh addUser.sh del user1` on terminal:

```
user added: user1
user user1 deleted
```

The result is the same, how can I fix it?

Comment: `"$arg1"="add"` is a single string of non-zero length, i.e. true.

Comment: Always check https://www.shellcheck.net/ first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @melpomene for the advice
The problem was the spaces in `[ "$arg1"="add" ]`
Change `[ "$arg1"="add" ]` to `[ "$arg1" = "add" ]` and it works perfectly.

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1="$1"
arg2="$2"
if [ "$arg1" = "add" ]; then
 if ! grep -q $arg2 "users.txt"; then
  sed -i -e 's/users:/users: \n  - '$arg2'/g' users.txt
  echo "user added: $arg2"
 else
  echo "user exists: $arg2"
 fi
fi
if [ "$arg1" = "del" ]; then
 if grep -q $arg2 "users.txt"; then
  sed -i -e 's/- '$arg2'//g' users.txt
  echo "user $arg2 deleted"
 else
  echo "not found $arg2"
 fi
fi
```